# How do I SSH into my Nova compute nodes

Tags: juju, openstack

I've got Openstack running using MAAS, and Landscape. I'm running into an error trying to launch an Instance, with the *Error: No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available.* problem.

In trying to troubleshoot I'm trying to find the Nova-Compute.log file, but I need to get there first and I can't seem to figure out which LXD machine its on.

From my MAAS server where I ran conjure-up I get:

```
juju list-machines  
Machine  State    DNS            Inst id              Series  AZ       Message  
0        started  192.168.2.138  te3f68               xenial  default  Deployed  
0/lxd/0  started  192.168.2.139  juju-a150c6-0-lxd-0  xenial           Container   started    
0/lxd/1  started  192.168.2.140  juju-a150c6-0-lxd-1  xenial           Container   started  
0/lxd/2  started  192.168.2.141  juju-a150c6-0-lxd-2  xenial           Container started  
0/lxd/3  started  192.168.2.142  juju-a150c6-0-lxd-3  xenial           Container started
```

**If I juju ssh to 0, I end up on my Juju Controller, but then if I perform a Juju list machines from there it says that Juju isnt installed.

The only machine that seemed to have Juju running was 0/lxd/1, but when I Juju list-machines I get:**

```
juju list-machines  
ERROR No model in focus.  
Please use "juju models" to see models available to you.
You can set current model by running "juju switch"
or specify any other model on the command line using the "-m" flag.*
```

**However under my MAAS subnets tab under used IP's I can see the virtual machines deployed across the MAAS nodes:** **I've highlighted the MAAS servers. Quiet-Boa is the node that I bootstraped to with Conjure-up which I'm assuming is the Juju controller, and trusty-Cicada is the node which I deployed to in Landscape. The remaining three nodes are where the Nova, Ceph etc were installed to. How does one know what is installed where? How does one SSH to the node once thats figured out? **

```
Used

IP Address  Type    Node    Interface   Usage   Owner   Last seen  
192.168.2.2 Automatic   **new-tuna**    eno1    Machine erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:03:51  
192.168.2.3 Static  juju-c13c4c-0-lxd-0 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:04:01  
192.168.2.50    Static  MaaS    enp0s25 Rack and region controller  MAAS    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 10:40:15  
192.168.2.101   Automatic   **fair-dingo**  eno1    Machine erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 12:53:55  
192.168.2.103   Static  juju-c13c4c-1-lxd-3 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:14:29   
192.168.2.104   Static  juju-c13c4c-2-lxd-2 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:15:01  
192.168.2.105   Static  juju-c13c4c-0-lxd-5 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:05:45
192.168.2.106   Automatic   **tight-wahoo** eno1    Machine erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:04:06
192.168.2.107   Static  juju-c13c4c-2-lxd-4 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:13:09
192.168.2.108   Static  juju-c13c4c-0-lxd-3 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:05:10
192.168.2.109   Static  juju-c13c4c-0-lxd-1 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:04:42
192.168.2.110   Static  juju-c13c4c-0-lxd-2 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:04:55
192.168.2.111   Static  juju-c13c4c-1-lxd-0 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:15:03
192.168.2.112   Static  juju-c13c4c-1-lxd-2 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:13:10
192.168.2.113   Static  juju-c13c4c-1-lxd-4 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:14:43
192.168.2.114   Static  juju-c13c4c-2-lxd-0 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:14:30
192.168.2.115   Static  juju-c13c4c-0-lxd-4 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:05:28
192.168.2.116   Static  juju-c13c4c-2-lxd-3 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:15:17
192.168.2.118   Static  juju-c13c4c-2-lxd-1 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:14:46
192.168.2.119   Static  juju-c13c4c-1-lxd-1 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 13:15:27
192.168.2.137   Automatic   **quiet-boa**   eno1    Machine erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 11:45:10
192.168.2.138   Automatic   **trusty-cicada**   eno1    Machine erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 11:55:43
192.168.2.139   Static  juju-a150c6-0-lxd-0 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 12:06:52
192.168.2.140   Static  juju-a150c6-0-lxd-1 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 12:09:10
192.168.2.141   Static  juju-a150c6-0-lxd-2 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 12:09:25
192.168.2.142   Static  juju-a150c6-0-lxd-3 eth0    Device  erniel29    Fri, 04 Aug. 2017 12:09:42  
192.168.2.206   Observed        Unknown BMC MAAS    Thu, 03 Aug. 2017 16:28:55  
192.168.2.207   Observed        Unknown BMC MAAS    Thu, 03 Aug. 2017 16:29:23  
192.168.2.208   Observed        Unknown BMC MAAS    Thu, 03 Aug. 2017 16:29:30  
192.168.2.214   Observed        Unknown BMC MAAS    Thu, 03 Aug. 2017 16:28:48  
192.168.2.215   Static
```

In the end, my main issue is that I don't quite understand the relationship between machines and who controls what. I've been pinging back and forth between Conjure-up docs, and Juju docs, and MAAS docs, but I can seem to find a cohesive architectural explanation of the overall system.

I would appreciate some assistance in understanding how to SSH into the various LXD's.

Update: I ran Nova service-list and got:

```
$ nova service-list  
+----+----------------+---------------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+  
| Id | Binary         | Host                | Zone     | Status  | State | Updated_at                 | Disabled Reason |
+----+----------------+---------------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+  
| 1  | nova-scheduler | juju-c13c4c-0-lxd-3 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-04T20:00:26.000000 | -               |  
| 2  | nova-cert      | juju-c13c4c-0-lxd-3 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-04T20:00:24.000000 | -               |  
| 3  | nova-conductor | juju-c13c4c-0-lxd-3 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-04T20:00:24.000000 | -               |  
| 11 | nova-compute   | new-tuna            | nova     | enabled | up    | 2017-08-04T20:00:20.000000 | -               |  
| 12 | nova-compute   | tight-wahoo         | nova     | enabled | up    | 2017-08-04T20:00:19.000000 | -               |  
+----+----------------+---------------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
```

So does this mean that Nova compute is on bare metal?
Also I fixed the original Issue which was the No Valid Host Error. I replaced the router and that seemed to do the trick. But I'd still like to know how to get all the nodes.